# springer svjour3 is not arranging citations by order of appearance

Tags: bibtex, sorting, springer

I want to arrange citations by order of appearance on springer svjour3 (template files could be find here https://github.com/jperkel/computed_manuscript/tree/main)

I tried to come up with a basic example where referencing starts with `[2]` instead of `[1]`.

Required files, I was not able to paste their source code since they are too long:

- `spmpsci.bst` file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jperkel/computed_manuscript/main/spmpsci.bst
- `svjour3.cls` file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jperkel/computed_manuscript/main/svjour3.cls
- `svglov3.clo` file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jperkel/computed_manuscript/main/svglov3.clo

---

sn-bibliography.bib :

```
@electronic{zoo,
title={zoo},
url = {https://github.com/mrocklin/heft},
lastvisited = {2022-04-04}
}

@electronic{doo,
title={doo},
url = {https://github.com/mrocklin/heft},
lastvisited = {2022-04-04}
}
```

main.tex :

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\smartqed
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}  % mathematics and physical sciences
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{Author 1 \at
              Location 1, \\ Department, University, Country \\
              \email{alper.alimoglu@boun.edu.tr}           %  \\
}
\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\keywords{bla1 \and bla2}
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}
~\cite{zoo}
~\cite{doo}
\bibliography{sn-bibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Wanted output would be references in order as:

```
[1] [2]

References

1. zoo. URL https://github.com/mrocklin/heft
2. doo. URL https://github.com/mrocklin/heft
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the documented behavior in the bst file that you link to

> The order in the reference list is alphabetical by authors.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any alternative bst file that can maintain arranging citations by order of appearance?

Comment: If there is no author like for the `@electronic` citing I assume they will be the first in ordering

Comment: @alper I'd have to trace the bst code, some styles sort such entries as empty, some will sort on the title or publisher if no author, it depends what the journal style is

Comment: @alper there are literally thousands of bst styles about half of them sort by author (which is by far the most natural system to me) and half don't sort so you get order of appearance, just pick one, but if you are submitting to a journal, it is the journal that gets to choose, not you.